# Where is Heinrich Martin Weber's grave located?

Tags: 20th-century, mathematics, famous-people

Where is [Heinrich Martin Weber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Martin_Weber) buried?

His full name is perhaps: 'Heinrich Martin Georg Friedrich Weber', or
'[Heinrich Martin Georg Weber](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Weber_(Mathematiker))' or as this historian amateurs site  claims '[Martin Georg Friedrich Heinrich Weber](http://www.s197410804.online.de/Personen/WeberGeorg.htm)'. Although most of the time he himself apparently simply went by the name 'Heinrich Weber'.

He was a famous German mathematician, he died in 1913 in Strasbourg, today's France.

I tried a search on the findagrave website, but there is no entry for his name. I also tried a multilingual search without success.

Comment: Full name is Heinrich Martin Georg Weber (German WP), though his obituary only states Heinrich Weber"; and [this site](http://www.s197410804.online.de/Personen/WeberGeorg.htm) even names him 'Martin Georg Friedrich Heinrich Weber' : The doc 'SUB Göttingen 8 Cod. MS. Philos 205 Beilage' states the funeral 'to start at Haus Taulering 33'… @njuffa not sure whether that was _his_ home?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that Heinrich Weber's grave is no longer extant. The city archives of Strasbourg provide an online [archive of burial records](https://archives.strasbourg.eu/archive/recherche/cimetiere/) that include those from the year [1913](https://archives.strasbourg.eu/archive/resultats/cimetiere/tableau/FRAMC67482_0003_238MW/n:241?RECH_unitdate_exacte=1913&type=cimetiere). We find Weber in the list of burials for the Cimetière Saint-Louis, Strasbourg, protestant section, 1893-1957, p. 80 (p. 83 of the [scan](https://archives.strasbourg.eu/ark:/39332/vtade5f4867963bcc29/daogrp/0/layout:table/idsearch:RECH_c1fe5b5e1cde2946f123bc371c52a623#id:1863477724?brightness=100.00&contrast=100.00)):

> Entry No. 1818. Weber Heinrich Prof. Age 70. Address: Taulerring 33. Date of death: May 17. Date of burial: May 19. Location of grave: division 2, row 3, grave no. 15. Lease expiration: September 30, 1968

The personal data from the entry agrees (with exception of the age of the deceased) with a [death notice](https://www.numistral.fr/ark:/12148/bd6t5292826j/f12.item.zoom) for Heinrich Weber published in a local newspaper: *Straßburger Post*, Sunday, May 18, 1913, No. 554, morning edition / second sheet:

> Heute Morgen um 6 Uhr verschied an den Folgen eines Schlaganfalls nach kurzer Krankheit unser lieber Vater, Schwiegervater und Großvater,
>
> **Professor**
> **Dr. Heinrich Weber**
>
> im 72. Lebensjahr.
> Straßburg i. E., den 17. Mai 1913.
> Prof. Dr. Rudolf H. Weber, Rostock
> Dr. med Richard Weber, Weißenburg i. E.
> Ida Weber
> Anna Weber
> Helene Weber, geb. Bauer, Rostock
> Anna Weber, geb. Nöldeke, Weißenburg i. E.
> und vier Enkelkinder
>
> Die Beerdigung findet Montag, den 19. Mai um 3 Uhr vom Hause, Taulerring 33 aus statt.

This tells us that Heinrich Weber died from a stroke at 6am on May 17 (Saturday), and that his funeral was set for May 19 (Monday), with funeral proceedings starting at 3pm at his residence at Taulerring 33 (today: 33 Boulevard Tauler).

For a detailed obituary see: A. Voss, "Heinrich Weber", *Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung*, Vol. 23, Leipzig: B. G. Teubner 1914, pp. 431-444 ([scan online](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN37721857X_0023?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B439%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D))

Comment: Nice. Could you also address this apparent naming conundrum (that's somehow left in the dangling comment below Q; 2 WPs giving different data, historian's blog giving a third option; so that _that_ can be deleted as well…)?

Comment: Your prerogative. But I'd consider answering the Q 'where is _his_ grave' to be significantly hindered if we do not really know what name _exactly_ would be registered in the files, databases, or _on his gravestone_ (provided there still would be one)? It also shows that this disconnect between his use of name, given name at birth and name usage by others (plus eventual errors) doesn't make QOP's life or that of anyone interested any easier (Q=not: 'too basic'…) Ie: 'a bridge useful to have and to hold'?